QGIS geopackage on shared network, project does not appear
I've created a geopackage containing a project, and i tried to share it on our local shared network so other users can access, but when we open the geopackage in another computer, the project does not appear. Any guesses of what could it be?

There are many reports of issues with trying to access geopackages on shared windows drivers. It is generally best not to store them there

See http://switchfromshapefile.org/#geopackage "One downside to GeoPackage is that the underlying SQLite database is a complex binary format that is not suitable for streaming. It either must be written to the local file system or accessed through an intermediary service. " Use PostGIS instead.

How are you opening the project? Have a look here

Geopackage is not suitable to be used on a remote drive, you should only use Geopackages that are stored locally. See here why:

One downside to GeoPackage is that the underlying SQLite database is a
complex binary format that is not suitable for streaming. It either
must be written to the local file system or accessed through an
intermediary service. http://switchfromshapefile.org/#geopackage

If you want a remote database with multi-user access, consider using PostGIS. It integrates very well with QGIS - in fact, QGIS development in the early 2000 started as a PostGiS viewer.
See Spatial Database Concepts with PostGIS or How to connect PostGIS to QGIS: A Step-by-Step Guide (Tutorial)

Just for the record, we have been using many geopackages from a shared drive for many years with very few problems. Only when you want to edit them by multiple users at the same time you can get in trouble...

OK, good to know... Still probably quite risky to do that for a productive system, knowing there could be problems. So if one has the choice than it would probably be better to stick to another solution.

Yes, we use a shared drive with some 1000s of geopackages as a repository of read/only data downloaded from 3rd parties intensely for GIS analysis,... . We have some geopackage files on a shared drive that are edited... but only sporadically and only by 3 or 4 people, so easy to coordinate not to have simultaneous edits. Data that is edited by many people (via a custom web based editor) is saved in Oracle Spatial in our case...

In our case, it would be just like Pieter, mostly repository and only 2-3 people editing sporadically. But can't find a solution as the project does not appear when trying to open the geopackage from the shared drive. I'm trying to open throught the browser panel > geopackage >project does not appear, only the layers stored in this geopackage.

We always use seperate qgz files to save the project in... I suppose that works for you as well or does that give issues as well?
